In bash why does the increment operator set the exit code to 1 if the input is zero
In the following bash session you can see the ((cnt++)) sets the exit code to 1 if cnt is zero, but not if the initial value is anything else, why is this?
$ cnt=0
$ echo $?
0
$ ((cnt++))
$ echo $?
1
$ echo $cnt
1
$ ((cnt++))
$ echo $?
0
$ echo $cnt
2


For the same reason that ((0)) sets $? to non-zero, while ((n)) sets $? to zero for any non-zero integer value of n.  Namely, someone decided that 0 should be treated as a "failure", while non-zero is treated as "success".  It's similar to 0 being treated as false, and non-zero is true.  It's a handy convention.

This is what lets you do something like while ((cnt--)); do ...; done, terminating the loop when the initially positive cnt finally reaches zero. (I.e., it's what links the notion of Boolean values to exit status.)

The Duplicate question is not the same, it is talking about let myvar++ and shows that ((cnt++)) actually works, ok its a similar question but not the same, and the behaviour is different.

cnt++ is the post increment operator, i.e. f=5;((g=f++)) would set g to 5. Therefore cnt=0; ((cnt++)) evaluates the expression to 0; that cnt is 1 afterwards is a side effect, but the ((....)) expression itself is 0 and therefore the exit code is 1.
